# Trying to add a non-linear positive trend line in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, transform

I'm currently in the process of trying to add a non-linear positive curve to my log-log graph, based off a quadratic model between variables y and x. I always receive the following message, even after attempting to change log mass(x).

> "Warning messages:
>   1: Removed 29 rows containing non-finite values (stat_smooth). 
>   2: Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`:
>   variable lengths differ (found for '(weights)') 
>   3: Removed 29 rows containing missing values (geom_point)."

```
ggplot(species,aes(x=BodyMass,y= MaleHornLength))+
  geom_point()+geom_smooth(mapping = aes(loglength,logbody),
  data = species, stat = "smooth",method = "lm", 
  formula = species$loglength ~ species$logbody +Time8,    
  se = TRUE,  na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA, inherit.aes = TRUE)+
  scale_x_continuous(trans='log',breaks = c(0,5,10,20,50,100,200,300,500))+
  scale_y_continuous(trans='log',breaks = c(0,5,10,20,50,100))+
  labs(x="Male Body Mass (kg)", y="Male Horn Length (cm)")+
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        axis.text=element_text(size=12, colour = "black"), 
        axis.title=element_text(size=14))
```

I would greatly appreciate any help regarding the matter. Thank you for your time.

Comment: What is the dataset in your example?

Comment: @eipi10, post as answer? (The only other answer would be to point to an example of "run `lm()` outside of ggplot, generate predicted values and SEs, use geom_line() + geom_ribbon() to add the predictions to an existing ggplot"

Answer (score 1):

Regarding warning number 2: The `formula` argument in `geom_smooth` can only have `y` as the LHS variable and `x` as the RHS variable. Default is `y ~ x`, but you can do, for example `y ~ poly(x, 2)` or `y ~ splines::bs(x, df=4)`. The formula is generic and will use the x and y columns specified in `aes`.

A few other things:

1. You don't need `data=species` in `geom_smooth`, since you've already provided `data=species` in the main ggplot call.
2. In your main ggplot call you have x=BodyMass and y=MaleHornLength, but in `geom_smooth` you have x=loglength and y=logbody. I can't see your data, so I can't be certain, but doesn't this reverse the x and y axis mappings between `geom_point` and `geom_smooth`?
3. Once again, I can't be certain without seeing your data, but does it make sense to plot points that are not log transformed and then overlay a regression curve based data that *are* log transformed? Also, it seems strange to log transform both the data and the axes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Within my dataframe, I have made a quadratic model using species non averages which I am now trying to apply to my graph which should show species averages. so i have two columns that are log transformed while on the graph I log transform the variables to fit the axis. Here is the code for the basic graph without any trend lines:

Comment: ggplot(species,aes(x=BodyMass,y= MaleHornLength))+
  geom_point()+scale_x_continuous(trans='log',breaks = c(0,5,10,20,50,100,200,300,500))+
                             scale_y_continuous(trans='log',breaks = c(0,5,10,20,50,100))+
                             labs(x="Male Body Mass (kg)", y="Male Horn Length (cm)")